# Find the solution of the Dirichlet problem in the half-plane y>0.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Find the solution of the Dirichlet problem in the half-plane $y>0$.
$${u_y}_y +{u_x}_x=0,  -\infty<x<\infty,y>0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x),-\infty<x<\infty$$
 $u$ and $u_x$ vanish as 
$$ \lvert x\rvert\rightarrow\infty$$ 
and $u$ is bounded as $$y\rightarrow\infty$$
I've tried hard  for this,but my answer is not matching.I've gone through  by applying infinite fourier transformation as my text book suggests,but I'm not even getting the intermediate equations correct.

Please help in getting over it.

Comment: Do you mean as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$ instead of $|x|\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: The solution is an integral involving _the Poisson kernel for the half-plane_.

Comment: @TrialAndError:Yes! SORRY for inconvenience.

Comment: @TrialAndError:Will you please give some hint how can we initiate the solution to this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method that would be used by Fourier is to separate variables, discard all of the resulting separated functions that are unbounded in the upper half plane, and then form integral linear combinations of the others.

Start by separating variables with $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$; to do this, plug into the equation and divide by $XY$:
$$
                        \frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y} = 0 \\
                      \frac{X''}{X} = \lambda = -\frac{Y''}{Y}.
$$
The values of $\lambda$ will always be real in well-posed problems of this type. If $\lambda > 0$ then $X(x) = Ae^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+Be^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$, and these are either unbounded at $x=+\infty$ or at $x=-\infty$. So you, you can replace $\lambda$ with $-\mu^2$ to simplify matters. Then the separated solutions that are bounded have the form
$$
               u_{\lambda}(x,y) = C(\mu)e^{i\mu x}e^{-|\mu|y},\;\;\; -\infty < \mu < \infty.
$$
There are other ways to write these by looking at $\mu > 0$ and $\mu < 0$ separately, but this form is convenient for use with the Fourier transform. You end up with a proposed solution
$$
         u(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}C(\mu)e^{i\mu x}e^{-|\mu|y}d\mu.
$$
In order to match the condition at $y=0$,
$$
              f(x) = u(x,0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}C(\mu)e^{i\mu x}d\mu \\
    \implies C(\mu) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i\mu x}dx
        = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{f}(\mu).
$$
Therefore,
$$
       u(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\mu)e^{-|\mu|y}e^{i\mu x}d\mu
$$
That's basically the solution. However, you can reduce to an integral involving $f$ instead of one involving its Fourier transform.

You can get rid of the transform for $f$ and rewrite as a convolution integral using the convolution theorem for Fourier transforms. This is done by writing $e^{-|\mu|y}=\hat{g_y}(\mu)$, which is achieved by inverse Fourier transforming $e^{-|\mu|y}$ with respect to $\mu$:
\begin{align}
       g_{y}(x) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|\mu|y}e^{i\mu x}d\mu \\
      & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\mu(ix+y)}d\mu+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{\mu(ix-y)}d\mu \\
      & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{y+ix}+\frac{1}{ix-y}\right)\\
      & = \frac{2y}{\sqrt{2\pi}(x^2+y^2)}
\end{align}
Then you apply the convolution theorem to obtain
$$
   u(x,y)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x')\frac{y}{(x'-x)^2+y^2}dx'.
$$
This is the Poisson integral for the solution.

Comment: (+1) How you tickled the bounded condition? How we can transform that condition using Fourier transform?

Comment: @zhk : I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: My question is how we can Fourier transform the bounded boundary condition? Because in book they transformed it to $U(k,y)\rightarrow0$ as $y\rightarrow\infty$. How is this possible?

Comment: @zhk : The conditions are cooked up so that you can instead Fourier transform the equation, assuming you have a solution, and then integrate by parts in order to convert the Fourier transform of $u''$ back to that of $u$. I've given you Fourier's way of building the solution, and then you can then verify that such conditions hold under reasonable assumptions on the boundary function $f$. Also: Keep in mind that $h(x,y)=y$ is a solution of Laplace's equation that vanishes on $\mathbb{R}$, which is why you needed boundedness.